# Flask-SQLAlchemy : Cannot access foreign keys from association table

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.7

I am new to **flask-sqlalchemy** and **mySQL**.

I have two tables named as **groups** and **switchboard**. I also have another association table named as **map_switchboard_group** which consists of **foreign keys**(primary keys of groups and switchboard).

I am writing a route which fetches all the **switchboard present in a group**.

Now, my problem is that I query my "map_switchboard_group" table by "group_uuid" column filter. I am able to get records but with **only "id"(primary key) column is accessible** and **rest all columns which are foreign keys are not accessible** or even seen in postman.

Hence, if I am not able to access the switchboard_uuid(foreign key) then I won't be able to fetch switchboards related to that.

My Group class:

```py
class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    group_uuid = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    group_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    switchboard_count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    MapSwitchboardGroup = db.relationship('MapSwitchboardGroup', 
    backref='groups')
```

My Switchboard class:

```py
class Switchboard(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'switchboard'
    switchboard_uuid = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    switchboard_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    master_mac_id = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    MapSwitchboardGroup = db.relationship('MapSwitchboardGroup', 
    backref='switchboard')
```

My MapSwitchboardGroup(Association) class:

```py
class MapSwitchboardGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'map_switchboard_group'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_uuid = db.Column(db.String(100), 
    db.ForeignKey('groups.group_uuid'))
    switchboard_uuid = db.Column(db.String(100), 
    db.ForeignKey('switchboard.switchboard_uuid'))
```

My query to fetch switchboard_uuid from my map_switchboard_group table:

```py
switchboard_uuid_list = MapSwitchboardGroup.query.filter_by(group_uuid=group_uuid).all()
```

Expected output should be:

```py
[ 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "group_uuid": "a2703a41-831f-4c6c-b995-1346bacd2ca3",
    "switchboard_uuid": "aa4fd8e7-9012-4c43-9f8e-baef3e968c57"
  }
]
```

Actual output that I am getting is:

```py
[
   {
     "id": 1
   }
]
```

Comment: What code are you using to generate output?  For example, If you grabbed the first record:  `foo = switchboard_uuid_list[0]` and tried to access the property `print(foo.group_uuid)` do you get an error?

Comment: Firstly I am using flask-marshmallow to deserialise the ```switchboard_uuid_list ``` object.
And yes like you have written I use ```print(foo.group_uuid)``` to try to access the property.
I catch the error in my exception block which says only 'group_uuid'.  Which probably means group_uuid is not present